# DB backups for production to DR without creating jobs in prod

Tags: sql-server

I had two servers(SQL 2005) A and B. B is Production server and A is DR. I want to take backups for B server databases from A server. We can not create any maintenance plans or jobs in B production server. We can create any jobs in DR server to take backups for Prod server. Is it possible? both are in different domain. If the servers are in same domain is it possible? and please send the procedure.

Please help me asap.

Comment: Welcome to the forums. Take the tour and check out the "help us to help you" blog (both at the bottom of the page). It is considered rude to put phrases like "asap" or "urgent" in your posts - if you need urgent assistance, hire a consultant - these forums are manned by volunteers. The forums are a great resource and you'll get the most out of them if you follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Ola Hallengren's [maintenance solutions stored procedures](https://ola.hallengren.com/) to accomplish what you are doing.

These stored procedures will allow you to backup via simple SQL scripts. You could then create a Job from the SQL Server Agent to run those backups once or on a scheduled basis.

[image]

Simple Example from the website:

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@Compress = 'Y',
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 24
```

This process will allow you to save your backups to a remote storage or locally.

You could also run this same process using [sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) to connect remotely to the server you are trying to backup

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i <MyScript.sql> -o <MyOutput.rpt>
```

And MyScript.sql would contain the backup script from above.

As long as the machine running the script is in same domain as the instance being backed up, there is no need to specify the user and password. This assumes that your domain login has the necessary server permissions to run a backup.

You must install the maintenance stored procedures before using them to backup, so please be sure to carefully read all instructions at this [page](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can take the backups from DR server for the backups of DB's on server B using Main'ce plans:

Below are the few points you need to check before you set up and create Maintenance plans for backing up the DB's of server B:

1. Make sure you can connect to server B (Prod) from the DR A, basically you have a good connection:
2. Make sure on the server B (Prod) you have shared the path where you want the backups to store, so that when you create maintenance plan on A you will be asked to provide the path for backup, so make sure the path is accessible from server A for the path on Server B.
3. Make sure you have correct user name and password for connecting to server B from A, either windows or SQL server Authentication:

Once checked above:

You can simply create the Maintenance plan on A, just need to to do below:

Once created a new maintenance plan, right click and edit on Backup database task, in connection drop down you have to specify a new connection, should not be local.

To create new, click on side NEW tab , give the connection name, fill the name of connection server that will be B(prod server) and then you can use sql server authentication method by providing valid user name and password with adequate permission to connect server B.

From here you can just proceed with further steps of creating database backup task:

For further details on how to use Maintenance plans refer to below link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191002.aspx